# How to make CD-quality WAV files using avconv?

Tags: audio, audio-cd, avconv

I want to make a CD using the audio tracks of some video clips. I was thinking of using `avconv` to convert the files. As far as the other steps go, I found some [instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CD_Burning#Command-line_CD-burning) on the Arch Wiki. This is the command that gets used:

```
for i in *.mp3; do mpg123 --rate 44100 --stereo --buffer 3072 --resync -w `basename $i .mp3`.wav $i; done
```

Obviously I am not dealing with mp3 files, so I need the `avconv` equivalent of the above one-liner for dealing with mp4 and flv files. I can provide additional information about the files' bitrates and such if necessary.

Comment: avconv may work the same way: `ffmpeg -i some.vid -map a:1 -ar 44100 out.wav`

Comment: MP3s and probably the codecs used for the audio channel of the videos is compressed in a *lossy* fashion. It is not CD quality and you will never be able to get your data back once thrown away. CD quality can only be obtained with *lossless* codecs.

Comment: @Marco: I don't think that was in doubt, but cdrecord still needs CD-quality WAV files. From man cdrecord, `All audio files must be in 44100 Hz 16 bit stereo format.`. My above comment only covers the sample rate, I forgot about the number of channels...